# Concurrent inserting to DB

Tags: java, jsoup, spring-batch, java.util.concurrent

I made a parser based on Jsoup. This parser handles a page with pagination. This page contains, for example, 100 links to be parsed. I created a main loop that goes over pagination. And I need to run async tasks to parse each of 100 items on each page. As I understand, Jsoup does not support async requests handling. After handling each of item I need to save it to DB. I want to avoid errors during insert into DB's table (if threads will use the same id for different items at the same time, if its possible). What you could suggest?
Could I use simple Thread instance to parse each item:

```
public class ItemParser extends Thread {
    private String url;
    private MySpringDataJpaRepository repo;

    public ItemParser(String url, MySpringDataJpaRepository repoReference) {
        this.url = url;
        this.repo = repoReference;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        final MyItem item = jsoupParseItem();
        repo.save(item);
    }
}
```

And run this like:

```
public class Parser {

    @Autowired
    private MySpringDataJpaRepository repoReference; // <-- SINGLETON

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int pages = 10000;
        for (int i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
            Document currentPage = Jsoup.parse();
            List<String> links = currentPage.extractLinks(); // contains 100 links to be parsed on each for-loop iteration
            links.forEach(link -> new ItemParser(link, repoReference).start());
        }
    }
}
```

I know that this code is not compilable, I just want to show you my idea.

Or maybe it's better to use Spring Batch?
What is best practice to solve this?
What do you think?

Comment: You can use Transaction to avoid errors during insertion and insertion will be really fast if you use transaction.

Comment: @utsavanand and what kind of isolation level should I use?

Answer (score 2):

If you use row level locking should be fine.  It might save problems to have each insert be a transaction but this has implications given the whole notion of a transaction as a unit of work (i.e. if a single insert fails do you want the whole run to fail and rollback?).

Also, if you use UUIDs or db-generated ids you won't have any collision issues.

As to how to structure the code, I'd look at using Runnables for each task, and a thread pool executor.  Too many threads and the system will lose efficiency for trying to manage them all.  I notice you're using spring, so take a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

Comment: so, it's possible to use data JPA repository to save DB (but before I should setup this repo to use row level locking)?

Comment: To be clear, row level locking is a sql db concept.  There are analogs in other storage technologies, but for sql dbs, it's something you configure in the database.  E.g., mysql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-locking.html